# How to perform update on binary blob in Firebird stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, blob, firebird, firebird-3.0

The challenge is in stored procedures to assemble a binary value to blob and then save the table. The problem is that the stored procedure works with the blob as text, e.g., if I want to insert into blob byte 4, than byte 52 is inserted (for byte ASCII number 4).

I tried different cast, but nothing works. If stored procedure update blob into a table, which is a parameter of the function, so it works fine.

How to work with binary values (full byte) in a stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC__TESTBLOB (
INID Integer,
INDATABLOB Blob sub_type 0 )
RETURNS (
RESULT Varchar(20) )
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE VAR_BLOB blob sub_type 0;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
  BEGIN
    --update tab_test set datablob = :INDATABLOB where id = :INID; --This work fine

    VAR_BLOB = CAST(4 AS BLOB(0));--not work, blob is still byte 52 (ascii number 4)
    VAR_BLOB = 3;--not work, blob is still byte 51 (ascii number 3)
    update tab_test set datablob = :VAR_BLOB where id = :INID;--This does not work

    RESULT = 'OK';
  END
  WHEN ANY DO RESULT = 'ERR';
  END
  SUSPEND;
END^
```

**UPDATE**
Firebird version 3.0.0.32483    64bit

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using, the answer could be very different depending on that.

Comment: Cross posted to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158537/1822

Comment: yes, i see, so i deleted it on dba.stack..., Now it's okay, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work, is that `cast(4 as blob(0))` will convert to `'4'` which is indeed 0x34 or decimal 52.

To be able to assign binary values, you need to use [binary string literals](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-string-constant) (introduced in Firebird 2.5):

```
VAR_BLOB = x'04'
```

Note that binary literals are comprised of pairs of hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Perfect. It was exactly what I was looking for but not found. I went through the Firebird documentation regarding the blob, but there was no mention of the use of binary data in stored procedures (probably i not know how to properly search :) ) thanks

Comment: @Majkl To be honest, I had some trouble finding the right reference as well. My answer initially included a link to the Firebird 2.5 release notes, and only later I found the right entry in the Firebird 2.5 language reference. I will see if I can get that improved, as I would have expected it under the section "Literals", but instead it was under "Common Language Elements".

Comment: he can also introduce his own BLOB type and then write BLOB-interpreting UDFs